# Is it possible mask input using a different placeholder?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, masking

Since my form has no labels, I would like to be able to use a different placeholder with Angular and Angular-UI-Utils-Mask:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="date"
        ui-mask="99/99/9999"
        placeholder="Birth Date"/>  
</div>
```

Using `jquery-inputmask` it works like a charm, but I had too many problems to make it work with Angular so I'm now trying to go Angular way, but Angular shows my input as:

```
Bi/th/Date
```

Here's a fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/XS4R6/

I also saw some people talking about ´ui-mask-placeholder´, but it does nothing.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

To clarify, I think it's just fine to use just `placeholders` since you also use `titles` (hint) so people always know what are they supposed to type in those inputs:

[image]

The input showing `__.___.___` is the one I'm using Angular UI Mask.

JQuery Inputmask works very fine, since it shows the 'name' placeholder and as soon as I mouse over or click the input it shows the mask.

Comment: I think it's fine to not use labels. Edited to show how the form will be and what Angular is doing. JQuery Inputmask works very fine, since it shows the 'name' placeholder and as soon as I mouse over or click the input it shows the mask.

Comment: I needed this functionality and had to ditch `ui-mask` and implement my own. :(

Comment: @JonathanRowny Do you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you can use another tag to simulate placeholder, maybe the code here is not very good, but I just provide another thought.

```
app.directive("myPlaceholder", ['$compile', function($compile){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        attr.$observe('myPlaceholder', initialize);
        var mask = '__/__/____';

        function initialize(value) {
            // label is not clickable in IE, that's the reason why we use span tag
            var fakePlaceholder = angular.element('<span class="placeholder">' + value + '</span>');
            // click placeholder to focus the input
            fakePlaceholder.on('click', function(){
                elem.focus();
            });
            elem.before(fakePlaceholder);
            $compile(fakePlaceholder)(scope);

            elem.on('focus', function() {
                fakePlaceholder.hide();
            }).on('blur', function() {
                if (elem.val() === mask) {
                    fakePlaceholder.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

demo on http://jsfiddle.net/XS4R6/19/  (jQuery required)